# electron.remote is undefined in render process

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to use dialog when a user clicks button, bug got an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dialog' of undefined`. The result from the console log is `undefined`

`main.js` file

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, './src/index.html'));

  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

`index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="create">Create New File</p>
    <p id="open">Open File</p>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.js` file

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
console.log(remote); // undefined

const open = document.querySelector('#open');
const create = document.querySelector('#create');

open.addEventListener('click', function () {
  remote.dialog.showErrorBox('error', '123'); 
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true
    }
```

Add `enableRemoteModule`. I think you are using the latest version of Electron and we can't use `remote` module on renderer by default. Need to add this flag to enable this.

Ref: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408

Comment: It's recommend to [don't enable the node integration](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content) but rather use  pre-load script.